# internally redirect from a subdir of a domain to another server on localhost (with a different port)

Tags: mod-rewrite, localhost

How can I redirect from a subdir (at `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.net/httpdocs/subdir`) to an internal url (`http:// localhost:8992/anApp`) without changing the url in the browser ?

What I want to have is something like this in the `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.net/httpdocs/subdir` :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /subdir http://localhost:8992/anApp
```

It does not work though. Why?
How does a better/working solution look like?

Comment: You can't, not without a proxy server anyway.  To talk to a different port or domain, the browser must initiate the request which means a redirect unless you have a proxy service in between.

Comment: FYI on terminology - "redirect" implies a change of URL in the browser, so what you really want is a "rewrite". You can use mod_proxy to set up a proxy as Michael mentioned and should be able to achieve what you want: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html